# If 2 spaceships approaches each other at 0.99c, how much blue shift would they see?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, waves, velocity, doppler-effect

Imagine these 2 spaceships moving at 0.99c toward each other and speed isn't additive how much blue shift would they see? I know how to calculate when the scenario is spaceship vs Earth but how about these 2 spaceships?

*new update*

here's what I got:

using Lorentz addition calculator to add their speeds give v=0.9999494975001263c

substitute the speed into relativistic Doppler effect calculator to find the amount shifted, z=-0.9949748743718667, tada!!!

btw I also substitute spaceship with hydrogen atom because the calculator need a valid input.

is my approach correct because I applied the relativistic Doppler equation without much modification for this special 2 moving spaceships scenario as hinted by user, Aaron Stevens?

Comment: Why do you think the typical Doppler shift equation won't work here?

Answer (score 1):

This is where it's easy to use rapidity:

$$ w = \textrm{atanh}\beta $$

which is additive. Moreover, the Doppler factor is:

$$ k = e^w $$

which means the combined doppler factor is:

$$ k' = e^{w'} = e^{w+w} = e^{2w} = k^2 $$

Comment: can you explain with a bit more words as I do not understand the equations?

Comment: $\beta$ is velocity in natural units. $w$ is called "rapidity", and is useful because it is the velocity-dependent thing that _is_ additive in SR. $k$ is what you asked about, the doppler factor, and it is multiplicative when chaining frames.